# Entity Framework 6 Linq results for master-detail

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a master-detail model using the following tables:

```
Orders
OrdID   DATE            CustID
========================================
1       01.01.2014      1
2       02.02.2014      2
3       03.03.2014      2
4       01.01.2014      4

OrderDetails
ID      OrdID   ProdID  Quantity
========================================
1       1       1       2
2       1       2       1
3       2       3       3
4       2       4       5
```

Now I want to have a Orders DataGridView and a OrderDetails Datagridview.
Orders DGV should look like this:

```
Orders
OrdID   DATE            Customer    Status
============================================
1       01.01.2014      CustOne     100%
2       02.02.2014      CustTwo     62.5%
```

And Details DGV like this (filtered on selected order):

```
OrderDetails
ID      Prod        Quantity    Status
======================================
1       ProdOne     2       100%
2       ProdTwo     1       100%
3       ProdThree   3       0%
4       ProdFour    5       100%
```

Lets say that the Status Field in OrderDetail is Calculated based on data from other 3-4 tables.
These tables are shown on the form, and they contain some product/order related details (production status, suppliers, etc.).
I did all this using Dataset and Datatables getting all tables from the database into a dataset, then making all the calculations using Linq results for populating other tables that had necessary relations between them, so I could bind them to datagridviews using bindingsources for master-detail.
Now i'm trying to achive this using EF. My goal would be to minimize data fetched from the database, and perform all the calculations in memory, rather than in the database.
Is there a way to create an model in EF, that would contain the filed that I need, and the data coming from the context, not from the database.(I'm pulling the Products Table, the Clients table, the OrdersTable, the OrderDetails table, etc. from the database into the Context. Tha table behind Orders DataGridView is created using joins from all these tables. I dont want to get the data in this table from the database using StoredProcedures, I want to get it using Linq from with the tables already in context).

THE QUESTIONs ARE:
I have entity:

```
Order with properties: OrdID, DATE, CustID
    and navigation properties: Customer, Orders.
```

and entity:

```
OrderDetail with properties: ID, OrdID, ProdID, Quantity
    and navigation properties: Order, Product.
```

How do I add a property to an entity, and this property is calculated, kind of like Expression in a datatable.
How do I display the Orders collection on a datagridview, showing Customer info on every row.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Is there a reason why you pull the records, and then calculate the required values rather than having the DB do it for you (and thus minimising data fetched)? 2.  Why do you not want to use Stored Procedures when it can often increase performance and they can be directly modelled in your EF model - `var query = myDbContext.MyStoredProcedure(para1, para2...)`?

Comment: I have to do lots of calculations, for one of the columns, and it uses custom functions... It's better to do it local in memory rather than on the Server.

Comment: OK - but beware of this if your database is on a seperate server to your application as it will act as a bottleneck which will become more apparent as your tables get bigger.  So for clarification, what exactly do you want help with?  Creating the EF model, or writing the LINQ query to fetch the data from an EF model you've already created?

Comment: @JonBellamy Please check the last paragraphs in the question.

Comment: When you use ORM like EF, you are not supposed to use SP.Have you checked .edmx model generated by EF, which gives you ability to add scalar/navigation property(entity property) & much more. DBContext of your model gives you ability to fetch data(Orders Collection) from database through linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst there is a very long way of answering your question, I believe there is an alternative to what you are trying to achieve.

For the calculated property, you need to create a Partial Class with the calculated property, but you would need to ensure that the navigation property is populated first:

'pre populate data and include any additional navigated items

```
Dim Query = DataContext.Orders.Include("OrderDetails").Where(Function(t) t.OrderID = x)
```

'create a new partial class on the OrderDetails entity then create a property to calculate status:

```
Public Partial Class OrderDetails
    Public ReadOnly Property Status As String
        Return = (100 / Me.Quantity) & "%"
    End Property
End Class
```

Ideally you should create a View Model for each datagrid, then as you populate it you can create your functional / calculational properties specific to the datagrid there, but by creating the partial classes on your Model you can re-use it in any application.